# web3.js-1.0.0-beta.36 - I can not connect to INFURA

Tags: infura, web3js-v1.x

Help with the solution

1. Installed the web3.js-1.0.0-beta.36 package on the hosting server.
2. Register and receive from Infura https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/myadress
   3.Where and what should I register to properly connect web3 to Infura

I would be grateful for any help.

[image]
[image]

In the Index.js file I change and line 55 gives me an error, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `web3.js` object like described [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#web3-object):

```
var Web3 = require('web3');

// "Web3.providers.givenProvider" will be set if in an Ethereum supported browser.
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/myadress');
```

After that, it should all work :) You can call subsequent functions like `web3.version`, etc...